# Make a button like circle without image in iOS using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode6, geometry

I am new in `Objective c`. I have some `buttons` on `storyboard`. I want to make all these `buttons` like circle.
All `buttons` are colored without images.
How i can do it using `objective c` ?

Comment: You want to change the shape of the buttons with code?

Comment: can anyone explain with some lines of code how i can make a button like circle using xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want to make all buttons round which is in storyboard, you have to take `For in` loop:

```
for(UIButton *btn in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
         btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
         btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.bounds.size.width/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: where i can use this loop?

Comment: In `ViewDidLoad` method

Comment: thanks a lot man. you are genius. its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.yourBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 50; // (Height of your Btn /2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.size.width/2;
yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
yourButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

***Make sure, button width and height are equal***

Answer (score 0):

```
self.button.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT/2.0f;
```